# Cannot find element after page refreshed - Selenium

Tags: javascript, dom, selenium, xpath, webdriver

I wanted to run a selenium test that checks whether it navigates to a new page when the button in the old page is clicked. Then I wanted to test whether it navigates back to the old page when the button in the new page is clicked.

The test works correctly when i click on the button on the first page and check whether the button element on the new page appears. But when i use selenium to click on the button element on the second page and check if the button element on the first page has appeared, it fails to find the button element on the first page, although i used the same button element to go the second page the first time and i can see that the first page is loaded. i tried usign the following wait statements:

```
 waitForPageToLoad()
 waitForTextPresent("", "text on first page")
 waitForElementPresent("" , //path to first button element)
 WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver,      10)).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("path to first button elment")));
```

None of the above wait statements work although the same element was found when the page was first initialized.

Comment: As far as I know, when refreshing pages you need to refresh also the bindings on the selenium server, meaning that the pointer you had to that button is gone once the page has changed and you need to repoint to it.

Comment: ok thanks, but what did you mean by repointing. because currently i have something like the following : List<WebElement> button = driver.findElements(By.xpath("xpath to button"); and then button.click(); . I did the same before and after the page refreshed, ut doesn't work the second time although the xpath is the same.

Comment: That was my guess but I see that you already repoint to the button after a page refresh, then my only guess left is that the code you added in the comment is ran before the button is actually visible, but it's just a guess.

Comment: okay, that is what i thought too, but the wait statements don't seem to work, although i see that the element has already appeared on the UI.

Answer (score 3):

Realized that the second time the first page is refreshed i had to first do driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.xpath("path to iframe")) as the application was inside an iframe. So it could  not find the elements the second time, unless i first switch to the iframe inside.